# MKMapView zoom User Location and Annotation

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I want my MKMapView to zoom 'User Location' and the Annotation as close as possible.
The map already show both, but is zoomed out to the whole country.
How can I do that?

And I don’t know why the Annotation and Pin are not animated.

My Code:

```
//Coords User
CLLocationCoordinate2D user_location;
user_location.latitude = mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude;
user_location.longitude = mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude;
//Coords Annotation
CLLocationCoordinate2D club_location;
club_location.latitude = [self.clubInfo.latitude doubleValue];
club_location.longitude = [self.clubInfo.longitude doubleValue];

MKMapPoint userPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(user_location);
MKMapPoint annotationPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(club_location);

MKMapRect userRect = MKMapRectMake(userPoint.x, userPoint.y, 0, 0);
MKMapRect annotationRect = MKMapRectMake(annotationPoint.x, annotationPoint.y, 0, 0);

MKMapRect unionRect = MKMapRectUnion(userRect, annotationRect);

MKMapRect unionRectThatFits = [mapView mapRectThatFits:unionRect];
[mapView setVisibleMapRect:unionRectThatFits animated:YES];

// Add an annotation
MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
annotation.coordinate = club_location;
annotation.title = self.clubInfo.clubName;
annotation.subtitle = @"Pin!";
[mapView addAnnotation:annotation]; // This was missing
[mapView selectAnnotation:annotation animated:YES];
```

[image: MapView]

Logs:

```
userRect: {{134217728.0, 134217728.0}, {0.0, 0.0}}
annotationRect: {{99775488.0, 152579328.0}, {0.0, 0.0}}

unionRect: {{99775488.0, 134217728.0}, {34442240.0, 18361600.0}}

mapView.visibleMapRect: {{96025087.6, 116070015.1}, {41943040.7, 54657025.8}}
```

Comment: Replace the image with new one, where we can see where the pin is placed.

Comment: @iMartin Image updated

Comment: Your User location is completetely diferent than the Club location. I think you are calling this method when User location is not yet available. It points to the center of world. Try to add the pin to the User location and you will see the difference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand well, you want those two annotations to be visible with maximum possible zoom. I found this solution that **does not reqire any calculations**.

```
// You have coordinates
CLLocationCoordinate2D user = ...;
CLLocationCoordinate2D annotation = ...;
// Make map points
MKMapPoint userPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(user);
MKMapPoint annotationPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation);
// Make map rects with 0 size
MKMapRect userRect = MKMapRectMake(userPoint.x, userPoint.y, 0, 0);
MKMapRect annotationRect = MKMapRectMake(annotationPoint.x, annotationPoint.y, 0, 0);
// Make union of those two rects
MKMapRect unionRect = MKMapRectUnion(userRect, annotationRect);
// You have the smallest possible rect containing both locations
MKMapRect unionRectThatFits = [mapView mapRectThatFits:unionRect];
[mapView setVisibleMapRect:unionRectThatFits animated:YES];
```

*CoreLocation and MapKit structures are hell.*

Comment: How can I get the User Coordinate ?

Comment: Like this `mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate`

Comment: I tried but did not work. Please check out my first post, I updated it.

Comment: Can you, please, log all the `MKMapRect` values? Use `MKStringFromMapRect`. Log also final `mapView.visibleMapRect`.

Comment: Well, the rect values are correct. But you need to add the annotation before selecting it. That's why you don't see anything. Call `-addAnnotation:` and then `-selectAnnotation:animated:`.

Comment: Can you edit my original post with it? I'm new with Objective C so I'm a little lost how to do that.

Comment: With the edit the Annotation now is visible, but the zoom continue as the image attached =/

Answer (score 5):

For anyone coming here later: The shortest way of doing this is (iOS7+) this:

Assuming you have a @property `MKMapView *mapView`, and an `MKPointAnnotation *theAnnotation`, call:

```
[self.mapView showAnnotations:@[theAnnotation, self.mapView.userLocation] animated:NO];
```

Now this could cause some problems if called too early (i.e. when `self.mapView.userLocation` is not yet set). If so, you can call in `viewWillAppear`:

```
[self.mapView.userLocation addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"location" options:0 context:NULL];
```

Then, implement:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"location"]) {
        [self.mapView showAnnotations:@[theAnnotation, self.mapView.userLocation] animated:NO];
    }
}
```

That way you're sure it's set. Don't forget to remove the observer at viewWillDisappear:

```
[self.mapView.userLocation removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"location"];
```

Answer (score -1):

Use these 4 classes - it works like a charm!

```
//MapViewController.h file

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
@interface MapViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>  {
    IBOutlet UIButton *buttonBack;
    IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
    IBOutlet UILabel *labelTitle;
    NSString *lon,*lat,*nickName;
    BOOL isFirstLaunch;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *lon,*lat,*nickName;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonBack;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *labelTitle;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
-(IBAction)buttonBackAction:(UIButton *)_btn;
-(void)zoomToFitMapAnnotations;
@end
```

//
//  MapViewController.m
//

```
#import "MapViewController.h"
#import "Annotation.h"


@implementation MapViewController
@synthesize buttonBack,mapView,labelTitle;
@synthesize lon,lat,nickName;

// The designated initializer.  Override if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
/*
 - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
 self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
 if (self) {
 // Custom initialization.
 }
 return self;
 }
 */
-(IBAction)buttonBackAction:(UIButton *)_btn{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:1];
}


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    CLLocationManager* locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [locationManager setDelegate:self];
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    NSLog(@"MapViewController");
    labelTitle.text = @"anscacorona.blogspot.in"
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    location.latitude = [self.lat floatValue];
    location.longitude = [self.lon floatValue];

    Annotation *annotation = [[Annotation alloc] init];
    annotation.theCoordinate = location;
    annotation.theTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",labelTitle.text];

    [mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
    [annotation release];
    mapView.showsUserLocation = 1;

    [self zoomToFitMapAnnotations];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

// Shows the location of both users. called when the device location changes to move the map accordinly. necessary ONLY once when the window is opened. afterwards the user can move the map as he choises. 
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    if (isFirstLaunch) {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D topLeftCoord;
        CLLocationCoordinate2D bottomRightCoord;

        topLeftCoord.longitude = fmin([self.lon floatValue], newLocation.coordinate.longitude);
        topLeftCoord.latitude = fmax([self.lat floatValue], newLocation.coordinate.latitude);

        bottomRightCoord.longitude = fmax([self.lon floatValue], newLocation.coordinate.longitude);
        bottomRightCoord.latitude = fmin([self.lat floatValue], newLocation.coordinate.latitude);

        MKCoordinateRegion region;
        region.center.latitude = topLeftCoord.latitude - (topLeftCoord.latitude - bottomRightCoord.latitude) * 0.5;
        region.center.longitude = topLeftCoord.longitude + (bottomRightCoord.longitude - topLeftCoord.longitude) * 0.5;
        region.span.latitudeDelta = fabs(topLeftCoord.latitude - bottomRightCoord.latitude) * 1.5; // Add a little extra space on the sides
        region.span.longitudeDelta = fabs(bottomRightCoord.longitude - topLeftCoord.longitude) * 1.5;  // Add a little extra space on the sides

        region = [mapView regionThatFits:region];
        [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
        isFirstLaunch = NO;
    }

}

-(void)zoomToFitMapAnnotations
{
    if([mapView.annotations count] == 0)
        return;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D topLeftCoord;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D bottomRightCoord;
    topLeftCoord.longitude = fmin(mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude, [self.lon floatValue]);
    topLeftCoord.latitude = fmax(mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude, [self.lat floatValue]);

    bottomRightCoord.longitude = fmax(mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude, [self.lon floatValue]);
    bottomRightCoord.latitude = fmin(mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude, [self.lat floatValue]);


    MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };

    CLLocationCoordinate2D userCoord = {[self.lat floatValue],[self.lon floatValue]};
    region.center = userCoord;
    region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.05f;//fabs(topLeftCoord.latitude - bottomRightCoord.latitude) * 1.1; // Add a little extra space on the sides
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.05f;//fabs(bottomRightCoord.longitude - topLeftCoord.longitude) * 1.1;  // Add a little extra space on the sides

    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
    [mapView regionThatFits:region];
}
/*
 // Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
 // Return YES for supported orientations.
 return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
 }
 */

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}
#pragma mark - View Lifecycle

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    isFirstLaunch=YES;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {

    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

//anotation classes- Annotation.h

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>


@interface Annotation : NSObject  <MKAnnotation>{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
    NSString *theTitle;
    NSString *restId;
    NSString *theSubtitle;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *restId;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *theTitle;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *theSubtitle;
@property CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
@end
```

//Annotation.m

```
#import "Annotation.h"


@implementation Annotation
@synthesize theCoordinate,theTitle,theSubtitle,restId;
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;
{
    return theCoordinate; 
}

// required if you set the MKPinAnnotationView's "canShowCallout" property to YES
- (NSString *)title
{
    return theTitle;
}

// optional
- (NSString *)subtitle
{
    return theSubtitle;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: Hello iMartin i don't know why you down voted it but i use this to code for my pickanddate app in iTunes to show two user location with maximum possible zoom and its working great!also check zoomToFitMapAnnotations method in it!SO please don't down voted until you check and test it!

Comment: I don't say it doesn't work, but it is not very good answer. One has to read through all the code and find out useful informations. It seems to me like even you don't know which part is relevant.

Comment: Once you improve your answer by removing irrelevant code, I will upvote ;)